# I cannot run my simple test app Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

after reading some chapters of a book I decided to try to recreate some of the topics. Just for practising purpose.

When I try to run it, Xcode gives me an error

```
 Thread1: signal SIGABRT
and the console shows: 2012-07-16 11:19:46.401 MyProject[595:11303] (null)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I am just trying to display a view with a table. 
Here is my code for the appDelegate:

```
#import "MyProjectAppDelegate.h"
#import "MyProjectViewController.h"

@implementation MyProjectAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    MyProjectViewController *myProjectViewController = [[MyProjectViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myProjectViewController];

    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And my other viewController:

```
#import "MyProjectViewController.h"

@interface MyProjectViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyProjectViewController

- (id)init{

    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    if(self){

        UINavigationItem *n = [self navigationItem];
        n.title = @"MyProject";

        UIBarButtonItem *addBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItems:)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButton;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"OI";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I've already tried to reset my simulator and restart my Mac. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u created the tableview in xib and made the delegate,datasource and outlet connections??

Comment: Wait, did you accidentally subclass UITableView and not UITableViewController?

Comment: I did create a xib file and then I deleted.

Comment: So what do I have to do in this sort of situation?